# Sharing filters between applications

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I am building a modular Padrino application to mount mutiple applications.

I am mounting a base application to `/`

```
class BaseApp < Padrino::Application
  ...
end
```

I am then mounting other appilications to other endpoints, such as `/clients` and these applications inherit from the base application:

```
class ClientsApp < BaseApp
  ...
end
```

This inheritence allows me to define all my settings, error handling and any included rack middleware in the `app.rb` for the `BaseApp` class.

So far so good. **But I would also like to share `before` and `after` routing between apps.** For example in my `BaseApp` controller code I want to do this:

```
BaseApp.controller do
  before do
    ...
  end
  after do
    ...
  end

  get :index do
    ...
  end
end
```

Rather than repeating these filters in my `ClientsApp` controller code, like so:

```
ClientsApp.controller do
  before do
    ...
  end
  after do
    ...
  end

  get :index do
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there anyway I can DRY up this code and specify the filters once in `BaseApp` and have them somehow inherited? I understand these filters are methods calls rather than methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use standard sinatra extensions, put under lib:

```
# lib/common_filters.rb
module CommonFilters
  def self.registered(app)
    app.before do
      ...
    end

    app.after do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Then in yours apps:

```
# app/app.rb
class MyApp < Padrino::Application
  register CommonFilters
end
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work - `NoMethodError: undefined method 'filters=' for ClientsApp:Class`

Comment: Thanks. Updated code doesn't throw an error anymore, but all routes in subclass application now return a 404. It's as if the routes are being overwritten/lost or something. Any other ideas?

Comment: Works great, I need to register the `CommonFilters` with each of my apps, but this is pretty DRY so I'm happy. Thanks!!